# How to write a file in Lua?

Tags: lua

I just want to write a file to somewhere. Here is my code:

```
file = io.open("test.txt", "w")
file:write("Hello World")
file:close()
```

but the app crashes at the first line with:

```
attempt to call field 'open' (a nil value)
```

Even trying with the [Lua online](http://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo) console keeps up the same error.

EDITED:
Here is my screenshot of the console
[image]

Comment: Your code should work fine in the standard Lua interpreter from [lua.org](http://lua.org). The online Lua demo is a restricted sandbox that can only write to stdout but cannot open files.

Comment: I edited my question adding my console screenshot

Comment: The screenshot is not from the standard Lua interpreter.

Comment: No, my environment is ZeroBrane Studio, the interpreter should be the same

Comment: Works for me in my copy of ZBS at its local console. The code you cite would also work in stock Lua, or in any Lua where the stock `io` library is loaded. The call to `io.open` itself could fail if the current working directory is not writable, but that would result in `file` being `nil`, which would produce different errors. Please check which Lua is the current interpreter in ZBS: in the Project menu, look at Interpreters. It is possible that you are not using the Lua you think you are. Also try it at a command prompt with stock Lua.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code to dump the keys of `io`:

```
for k in next,io do
  print(k)
end
```

Lua online outputs:

```
write
```

Which makes sense when you think about it:

Sandboxing works by restricting what can be done, including removal of unsafe functions.

Comment: I'm using Lua to program a bberry app. It seems that Lua can't write or do anything to the Bberry filesystem, as your code returned an empty result in my case. Good Point